# Use threejs WebGLRenderer.render function Get Stencil Result

Tags: javascript

If is there some way to get the stencil result by using WebGLRenderer.render as a texture in threejs?

I'm learning the stencil buffer in threejs, and have a problem with it. I create a Mesh with THREE.TorusKnotGeometry and a material which is always pass the stencil test and stencil-writable(write as 1), another Mesh with THREE.PlaneGeometry and material stencilFunc is THREE.NotEqualStencilFunc, then when I render these two and set a rendertarget to get the texture, the result seems have no effect by stencil ? Can render include the result of stencil ? I wish to get a texture of stencil result! if anyone konws, please help, thanks! Here's some Code:

```
// create a mesh
const a = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(400, 100, 128),
   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      colorWrite: false,
      depthWrite: false,
      stencilWrite: true,
      stencilFunc: THREE.AlwaysStencilFunc,
      stencilZPass: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
      stencilFail: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
      stencilZFail: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
      stencilRef: 1,
   })
)

// create a plane so I can see the mesh through across this plane
const b = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000),
   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      stencilWrite: true,
      stencilRef: 0,
      stencilFunc: THREE.NotEqualStencilFunc,
   })
)
b.position.set(0,0,500)

// add to scene
scene.add(a)
scene.add(b)

// create a camera to render
const cam = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1000, 1000, 1000, -1000)
cam.position.set(0,0,1000)
cam.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))
cam.udpateMatrix()
cam.updateProjectionMatrix()

// a renderTarget
const renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(1024, 1024)

// render the target
renderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget)
renderer.render(scene, cam)
renderer.setRenderTarget(null)

// this is what i want
const texture = renderTarget.texture
```